# Защита от пересечения генерируемых объектов. Unity

Tags: unity3d, процедурная-генерация

На сцене во время игры случайно генерируются игровые объекты. 
 Нужно сделать так, чтобы созданные объекты не пересекались (то есть не накладывались друг на друга). 
Пока я использую вот это:

```
// Повторяем пока не найдется свободное место или пока кол-во попыток не станет больше 10
for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 10; attempt++)
{
    objects[i] = Instantiate(objectToGenerate, position, Quaternion.identity, parent);

    if (objects[i].GetComponent<CollideManager>().isTriggered)
    {
        Destroy(objects[i]);
    }
    else break;
}
```

К объекту objectToGenerate прикреплен компонент CollideManager. Переменная isTriggered равна true в случае если объект пересекается с другим объектом.

 Вот код компонента:

```
public class CollideManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isTriggered = false;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Static")
        {
            isTriggered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Но весь этот код не работает. 
 Методом тыка, гадания на кофейной гуще и отладки выяснил, что это скорее всего связано с тем, что unity не успевает обработать столкновение нового объекта со старыми за нулевой промежуток времени между этой строчкой:

```
objects[i] = Instantiate(objectToGenerate, position, Quaternion.identity, parent);
```

и этой:

```
if (objects[i].GetComponent<CollideManager>().isTriggered)
```

Поэтому я решил переделать все это в сопрограмму и добавить задержку:

```
objects[i] = Instantiate(objectToGenerate, position, Quaternion.identity, parent);

yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

if (objects[i].GetComponent<CollideManager>().isTriggered)
{
    Destroy(objects[i]);
}
else break;
```

Но теперь

1. Игра начала подвисать.
2. Объекты появляются прямо на глазах у пользователя, причем в самых неожиданных и неудобных местах. (Игрок идет, идет и вдруг прямо перед ним появляется убивающий его предмет)

Еще я пробовал вместо `WaitForSeconds` использовать `WaitForFixedUpdate`, но это не сработало: объекты накладывались друг на друга. 
Как заставить все это работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Кидать **Physics.OverlapSphere,OverlapBox** или **OverlapCapsule** (и лучше **NonAlloc** версии). Можно более упрощенные аналоги типо **Physics.Check(sphere,box,capsule)**. В **2D** версии еще **Circle** и **Area** добавляется. Тип и размеры(я бы брал увеличенный в 1.5 раза) можно брать от генерируемого объекта. Получите все коллайдеры в этих областях. ***99% гарантия*** качества(1% оставим на неожиданные открытия особенностей).
2. В момент генерации, создать массив записей (**точка - объект**), и каждый кадр считать расстояние от точки до объекта, если он выйдет за определенную дистанцию, считать что точка освободилась. ***50% гарантия***, и много ограничений(а если объекта обратно вернется, или там окажется другой объект и т.д.).